Apache Commons Configuration2 and XML Schema validation?
I want to load XML configuration via Apache Commons Configuration2 but also perform XSD validation. The XSD shall not be linked in the (potentially untrusted) configuration file but come from the application.
I could neither find matching examples in the documentation nor in StackOverflow. The one question that is similar to mine has a response only applicable to Apache Commons Configuration1 and it's answer is not applicable for me.
How can I have the XML configuration file loaded and validated?
Edit: Someone voted this question needs more details, so here they are.
The example for XSD validation in the Apache Commons Configuration documentation looks like this:
Parameters params = new Parameters();
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> builder =
    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration>(XMLConfiguration.class)
    .configure(params.xml()
        .setFileName("myconfig.xml")
        .setSchemaValidation(true));

// This will throw a ConfigurationException if the XML document does not
// conform to its Schema.
XMLConfiguration config = builder.getConfiguration();

The intention here is that an XML configuration file (myconfig.xml) is read and validated according to the XSD schema. Which schema? Well, it needs to be referenced inside the XML document. What I want instead is that my application mandates which XSD schema shall be used for validation. So I'd expect at some point in the code that an XSD schema is specified and that it will be used for validation. Here is what I tried:
File f = new File(xmlfile);
log.info("Reading {}", f.getAbsoluteFile());

URL url = getClass().getResource("/schema/configuration.xsd");
log.trace("loading XSD from {}", url);

SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(url.openStream());
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setSchema(schema);
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(false);    // ignore XSD references within the document
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
MyErrorHandler meh = new MyErrorHandler();
db.setErrorHandler(meh);
db.parse(f);                     // <<<=============== note this line

Parameters params = new Parameters();
params.xml()
        .setSchemaValidation(true)
        .setDocumentBuilder(db);

FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(XMLConfiguration.class)
        .configure(params.xml().setFile(f));
config = builder.getConfiguration();

Please note the line db.parse(f);:

With that line the document gets validated and I see MyErrorHandler to receive warnings, errors and fatal errors.
Without that line the document gets loaded regardless of it's validity.

It means although my DocumentBuilder is configured for correct validation, having passed it into the configuration builder using params.setDocumentBuilder() does not help.

I haven't tried this, but perhaps you can use params.xml().setDocumentBuilder(...). Get an instance of DocumentBuilderFactory, set its Schema and other properties, create a DocumentBuilder and use that. You can get a Schema through SchemaFactory.

Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed I am trying this. Can load a schema, but so far any document seems valid.

Ok, it took me a while to figure out why commons configuration would just not do the validation. I passed in the parameter wrongly. Here's what I have working now:
    File f = new File(xmlfile);
    log.info("Reading {}", f.getAbsoluteFile());

    URL url = getClass().getResource("/schema/configuration.xsd");
    log.trace("loading XSD from {}", url);
    
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(url.openStream());
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setSchema(schema);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setValidating(false);    // ignore XSD references within the document
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    MyErrorHandler meh = new MyErrorHandler();
    db.setErrorHandler(meh);
    
    Parameters params = new Parameters();
    
    FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(XMLConfiguration.class)
            .configure(params.xml()
                    .setValidating(true)
                    .setSchemaValidation(true)
                    .setDocumentBuilder(db)
                    .setFile(f)
            );
    config = builder.getConfiguration();

Mind the fact that the validator has to be set where params are applied. My initial code (see question) tries to cover it differently - and wrongly.

That dbf.setValidating(false) seems odd. Is that to let Commons Configuration do the validation and not the DocumentBuilder?

One more suggestion: use getClass().getResourceAsStream(...) to directly get an InputStream. I'd also use try-with-resources to close it.

dbf.setValidating(false) is necessary to not get errors for documents without schema reference. I added a comment there as it is indeed misleading. I prefer to see the URL I'm loading resources from, hence no getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)
